# Convert SQL statement to Linq / Lambda Query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

Im using MEF and executing a task which needs to be grouped with aggregate functions only when it returns more than 1 record. I need both the Max of the start hour and the min of the end hour grouped into a single record like my sql would result in on the restuled task

```
var ohs = await Bl.UoW.Repositories.OperatingHours
    .FindInDataSourceAsync(oh => ((oh.ProductId == productTypeId 
        && oh.StateId == state) 
        || (oh.StateId == complianceHours.State)));
```

Here is the SQL that gets me basiccally what I need when more than 1 record returned

```
SELECT 
    StateId,
    MAX(ComplianceHourStart),
    MIN(ComplianceHourEnd)
FROM 
    OperatingHours 
GROUP BY
    StateId
HAVING 
    StateId = 'CA'
```

So when more than 1 I can filter it further but not sure how to achieve max and min?

```
if (ohs != null && ohs.Count() > 1)
{
    //
    ohs = ohs.GroupBy(x => x.State).Max(x => x.ComplianceHourStart?...

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your SQL, this should be close:

```
var result = context.OperatingHours
                    .GroupBy(oh => oh.StateId)
                    .Select(oh => new {StateId = oh.Key, 
                                       MaxStart = oh.Max(x => x.ComplianceHourStart),
                                       MinEnd = oh.Min(x => x.ComplianceHourEnd)});
```

...although I'm not sure why you are grouping when you are restricting the state id column (group key). The following should also suffice:

```
var result = context.OperatingHours
                    .Where(oh => oh.StateId == 'CA')
                    .Select(oh => new {MaxStart = oh.Max(x => x.ComplianceHourStart),
                                       MinEnd = oh.Min(x => x.ComplianceHourEnd)});
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
ohs = ohs.GroupBy(x => x.State)
    .Select(g => new 
    { 
        //You need to make a choice on StateId, here... First one?
        StateId = g.First().StateId, 
        MaxComplianceHourStart = g.Max(o => o.ComplianceHourStart),
        MinComplianceHourEnd = g.Min(o => o.ComplianceHourEnd) 
    });
```